# Different of Exif tag between Android 4.4 and older?

Tags: android, exif

Here my problem, I tried to get GPS location from exif tag so I find these code on the net:

```
Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
String exifString = "Exif: " + filePath;
exifString += "\nGPS related:";
exifString += "\nTAG_GPS_DATESTAMP: "+ exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP);
exifString += "\nTAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP: "+ exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP);
String attrLATITUDE = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
String attrLATITUDE_REF = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
String attrLONGITUDE = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
String attrLONGITUDE_REF = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);
if ((attrLATITUDE != null) && (attrLATITUDE_REF != null)
    && (attrLONGITUDE != null)
    && (attrLONGITUDE_REF != null)) {
if ("N".equals(attrLATITUDE_REF)) {
    lat = convertToDegree(attrLATITUDE);
} else {
    lat = -convertToDegree(attrLATITUDE);
}
    if ("E".equals(attrLONGITUDE_REF)) {
    lng = convertToDegree(attrLONGITUDE);
} else {
    lng = -convertToDegree(attrLONGITUDE);
}
    exifString += "\nTAG_GPS_LATITUDE: " + lat;
    exifString += "\nTAG_GPS_LONGITUDE: " + lng;
}
textView.setText(exifString);
```

I run the above code on 3 devices:

1. Nexus 7 (Android 4.4.2)
2. Tablet F7HD (Android 4.0.4)
3. Genymotion (Android 4.3)

Option "Store location" is enable on all of them. Then I take photo on each, the location is stored on these photos because I open "Photos" application (Google+), open photos and choose Details, the application return exactly the location where photo is taken.

But when I run my code, only the photos captured on Nexus 7 return back the GPS information. The rest return null. I copy Nexus 7's photo to my Genymotion and F7HD, my code also work fine.

Any idea? I really need to get GPS information to finish one task in my capstone project.

Comment: Have you tried copying a photo from the F7HD or Genymotion to the Nexus 7, and checking whether your code parses it correctly?

Comment: I already did, but only the Photos from Google+ can read it, my code doesnt

Comment: For short, my code only work with photos captured on Nexus 7. I dont know why it doesnt work with the other.

Comment: First, does your Tablet have a **GPS module**, second, isn't Genymotion is an **emulator**?

Comment: First, my tablet have a GPS module absolutely. Second, Genymotion is just an emulator but it also emulate the GPS, I toke a photo on Genymotion and the app Photos in Google+ still recognize gps location in that photo.

Comment: Have you verified in the camera app's configuration that geo tagging is on? I know my device came with geo tagging off.
I suspect that google+ is using some non-standard method to extract the geo location from the photos, because they don't really have a geo tag in their exif.

Comment: Of course, from my question above "Option "Store location" is enable on all of them". I also think that Google+ come up with some other methods :(